# Azure Active Directory v2.0 doesn't seem to support OAuth session management

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory

We are using Azure Active Directory as an ID Provider, but we're having difficulty implementing single sign-out using the v2.0 platform because the support for OAuth 2.0 session management seems to have disappeared.

In the v1.0 documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v1-protocols-oauth-code) an authentication response is documented as returning a **session_state** parameter. But in the v2.0 documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow) that parameter has disappeared.

Similarly, if you view the openid configuration for a tenant on the v1.0 well-known url, a **check_session_iframe** url is defined. Do the same with the v2.0 well-known url, and that item is missing.

You'd think that such a major difference might be commented on somewhere in the documentation, but I can't find a reference anywhere, even on this page comparing the two protocols:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/azure-ad-endpoint-comparison

Does anyone know what's going on?